# Why is the variable unknown?

Tags: typescript

Please look at this example. I wonder why the p-parameter is unknown in the function test2. I expected p to be known as a number.

```js
interface MyInterface<A,B>{}

class MyClass<A,B> implements MyInterface<A,B> {}

function test1<A,B>(p:MyClass<A,B>, callback:(p:B)=>void){}

function test2<A,B>(p:MyInterface<A,B>, callback:(p:B)=>void){}

const myInstance = new MyClass<string,number>()

test1(myInstance, (p)=>{    
    // Here p is a number
}) 

test2(myInstance, (p)=>{
    // Why is p unknown?
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your interface is empty; in a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) like Typescript, an empty interface is implemented by every class regardless of what members the class actually has. Consequently, your class doesn't just implement `MyInterface<A, B>`, it also implements `MyInterface<boolean, string>` and every other possible assignment of types to the type parameters of `MyInterface`, because it (trivially) has all of the members required to implement the interface with those type parameters, whether or not it is explicitly declared as doing so with an `implements` clause.

As such, Typescript cannot infer what `A` and `B` should be for `test2` because literally any types would be compatible; for example, `test2<boolean, string>(myInstance, (p) => { /* ... */ })` compiles with no errors and `p` is of type `string`.

If the interface has a member (and the class implements it) such that the `A` and `B` parameterising the class must be the same as parameterising the interface, then `p`'s type will be inferred correctly in both functions:

```
interface MyInterface<A,B>{
    foo(x: A, y: B): void;
}

class MyClass<A,B> implements MyInterface<A,B> {
    foo(x: A, y: B): void {}
}

test2(myInstance, (p)=>{
    // p: number
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5ryQHgEEAaAIQD4BvAKGTuRgHtGAKADwC5kTl0vSAlFwBujYABMA3NQC+1aggA2cAM4q06AMLK1RMuWTAAtgAdFEIxHDqM2SLEQQ9FZDXoNm7Ljz7JBIsXFXOTlqGABXEAQwYEYQZEgVMABGZ3IWEw4MbVUVNOJkBDhFRQAjRABrDgyOQQBeclEJAUpQiKiYuISIJIAmNJrbHAcCEgoCopLyhCqa+sbAltCEOKTkIywQJLgolDrkEAgAdw0c3SSoUABzYhBwo1LodIF5RJSWDext3YKMgQbKO5aPQAPQg5AACWgKBMhnUcAO90eUFkAmQrx6YF6H023yQvxM-yowLoYOQmURD2gqPRQA)